# How do I pull different price values from table in database?

Tags: php, html

I have a shopping cart summary page set up to access data from a database via phpmyadmin. I am trying to configure the summary page to display different prices based upon the the different purchase options chosen by the user. In the table, you will see that I have 4 different columns for every product. I would like the price to be pulled based upon each option(i.e. basic, premium, unlimited, and exclusive) already stored in the cart session array.

`cart summary snippet`:

```
<div class="shopping-cart">
    <h6>My Cart</h6>
    <hr>
    <?php
    $total = 0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $product_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');
        $product_option = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'option');
        $result = $database->getData();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            foreach ($product_id as $id) {
            if($row['id'] == $id) {
           cartElement($row['product_image'],$row['product_name'],$row['basic'],$row['id']);
                                $total = $total + (int)$row['basic'];
            }
         }
         }
      } else {
        echo "<h5>Cart is Empty.</h5>";
      }
      ?>
</div>
```

`phpmyadmin table snippet outline`:

​

| id | basic | premium | unlimited | exclusive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 60 | 90 | Make an offer. |
| 2 | 30 | 60 | 90 | Make an offer. |
| 3 | 30 | 60 | 90 | Make an offer. |

​

Comment: Umm I am still fairly new but it’s just a way to represent mysql database right? Like to make life easier and data more user friendly... My bad for poorly phrasing the question. How would I go about selecting data from my database based on my input options stored in my session cart array?

Comment: what columns do you have in your database table that you want to display ... and where is this query ?

Comment: I already have the prices displayed. I am just trying to figure out how to take the session cart array and pull prices based upon stored ‘options’ in the cart array. Each ‘option’ has a value that corresponds to basic, premium, unlimited, exclusive which is supposed to represent the table column. I am trying to get ready to start a checkout process for my website but right now I would like to show the cart summary to the customer and was told it is important to always reference your table rather relying on post method because it is not safe.

Comment: Right now with my current function I am only pulling out the ‘basic’ column so it looks like each product has the same price but in reality it varies depending on the input (i.e. ‘options’).